# Import project with no .project file

Tags: android, eclipse, import

I am trying to import a project in Eclipse (it's the [Google Play services library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code), to use with Google Maps Android API v2, downloaded from the SDK Manager and located on my computer at `<android-sdk-folder>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib`).

It's not working and from what I've found, because of the absence of the `.project` file at the root of the project. Eclipse says "No projects are found to import".

[Here is a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlSgj.png)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you following these steps: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8431 ?

Comment: For the Android Studio walkthrough: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25320545/293280

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Create a new Android project from existing source instead of importing it.

Comment: Thank you ver much for your answer. I occupied myself with this problem for more than 4 hours untill I read ur answer.

Answer (score 5):

**Be Careful, Follow these steps and save your time**

1. Right Click on your Project Explorer.
2. Select New-> Project -> Android Application Project from Existing Code
3. Browse upto this path only - "C:\Users**your path**\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services"
4. **Be careful brose only upto - google_play_services and not upto google_play_services_lib**
5. And this way you are able to import the google play service lib.

Let me know if you have any queries regarding the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I tried to import a general project instead of importing an android project.

Answer (score 0):

my solution to this was

1.- Copy and paste google-play-services_lib to your Desktop

2.- Import using an existing project

```
Select New -> Existing Project in your Workspace I selected Desktop directory checked copy projects to your workspace and Finish
```

it worked

maybe if you use the original directory it is too large path and maybe eclipse cut it (I am suposing it)