# Add Google Play Service into eclipse workspace Android

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, android-library

I am trying to implement Admob in my Android app.I found the way to add google play services from sdk>extras>google_play_services.I have imported into my workspace but I cant able to add it my project.The selection of project is not highlighted.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: For the Android Studio walkthrough: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25320545/293280

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have imported your **Google_play_services_lib** in your project you have to enable your "Copy to WorkSpace" checkbox. So you can find that library project in Eclipse. After that you have to go to

Right click on project -> Go to properties -> Click on Android from left bar -> Add Library  -> Click there you will find google_play_service_lib -> Click Apply and ok.

So it will be added as a library project to your project.

Second option is that you can import **GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar** jar file into your ***libs*** folder.

Comment: still I can't able to add it.I removed google-play-service-lib from my workspace and tried.

Comment: have you try to add jar file?

Comment: No I dont have jar file.I dont have admob account so cannot able to download jar file

Comment: Its a free. you can download it from internet.

Comment: If you dont mind can you send the link where can I get the jar file and one more thing can I use other mobile ad networks like revmob,leadbolt in it

Comment: It is also available here ***Your Drive:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130729\sdk\extras\google\admob_ads_sdk\GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar***

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

-> Right click on project
-> Go to properties
-> Click on Android from left bar
-> Scroll down you will see Add Library options there
-> Click there you will find google_play_service_lib
-> Click Apply and ok.

Comment: I cant find google_play_service_lib in project selection window

Comment: first you have to import google_play_services_lib in to same workspace where your project is located.

Comment: Yeah I have imported that into my project workspace.But I cant able to  add it

Comment: just write click on google_play_services_lib and go to android tab, check there is "isLibrary" check box is selected or not?

Comment: I can able to add other project to my app.But not able to add google-play-service-lib

Answer (score 0):

Answered in here:

[Import project with no .project file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414170/import-project-with-no-project-file)

Just create a new project with the existing source file, then choose the google-play-services-lib files you copied to your workspace from the Android SDK folder as explained in here:

https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution. This worked for me.

After import google-play-services_lib to your workspace, go to this project and look for project.properties

and this line at the end:
android.library=true

For Example:

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-20
android.library=true
```