# Adding Google Play Services to non-gradle Android Studio project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-services

I have an existing project that was built without gradle for Android Studio
and I'm trying to get Google Play Services imported to fix a 
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable` exception.

The only problem is it doesn't seem possible... I've considered porting it to
gradle but the codebase is rather large (40+ Activities) and it would be a
nightmare for someone like me, who's never used gradle before, to accomplish.

I've trying importing the Google Play Services project from the SDK but it
hangs forever "creating gradle files".

Anyone have any experience loading this library to a non-gradle project before?

As an aside, I've tried loading the project into Eclipse to see if I could do
something that way, but the build paths self-destruct to where I've spent hours
trying to sort through them to no avail.

Comment: "was built without gradle for Android Studio" -- AFAIK, all Android Studio builds go through Gradle.

Comment: The amount of activities in your project doesn't make implementing Gradle any more complicated.  It's very simple to switch to Gradle.

Comment: I use Google Play Services in AS without gradle in my current project - it was one I started in IntelliJ idea and ported over to AS (without gradle) when it came out last year. Adding the Play Services to my project was not a major issue for me (it did not hang on gradle files).I used some stuff from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960315/importing-google-play-services-lib-into-intellij-idea-12-and-13) question to get it working. Or you could try using IntellJ instead of AS to add it and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Copy the library from the `SDK/Extras` Directory

1. Use your SDK Manager to download the **Google Play Services** - it'll be found under the **Extras** directory.
2. Go to your Android SDK directory and find the `google-play-services_lib` directory, for me this was in the Android Studio package:

   `/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/`
3. Copy this **entire directory** to your project's `libs` directory.
4. Add this as a module dependency as you normally would. *(For Android Studio, see below for step-by-step instructions.)*
5. You'll need to add a `meta-tag` to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file as well, that looks like this:

   `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`
6. Profit and Party?

#### Android Studio Steps

*Steps to add the library project as a module dependency once it's already in your `libs` directory.*

1. `File > Import Module`.
2. Select the `google-play-services_lib` directory under your `libs` directory.
3. Ensure `Create module from existing sources` is selected and click `Next` until you finish the wizard.
4. `Project Structure` > `Modules` (far left) > Select Your App > `Dependencies` tab > `+` > `Module Dependency` > `google-play-services_lib`.
5. `Project Structure` > `Modules` (far left) > Select `google-play-services_lib` > `Dependencies` tab > + > `Jars or directories...` > Find and select `libs/google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar`.

   **Make sure you click the `Export` checkbox for this dependency.**

   [image: Check the Export checkbox]
6. Profit and Party?

*Many thanks to Adama Speakman's [post](http://speakman.net.nz/blog/2013/06/23/adding-google-play-services-to-an-android-studio-project/) for the specific Android Studio steps.*

JP

Comment: Hi, I am having trouble at step 2. After specifying the `google-play-services_lib` directory, it doesn't enable the next button, like [this](http://tinypic.com/r/ei8ak7/8). Please help if you can.

Comment: Are you on Android Studio? Which version?

Comment: I solved it by adding a build.gradle file into the `google-play-services_lib` folder. Looks like AS bases on this file to detect whether it's a valid module or not. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Also from AS 0.4.2 onwards, there's a simpler way: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624827/android-studio-with-google-play-services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624827/android-studio-with-google-play-services).

Comment: @KhanhNguyen Glad you found the solution. That "easier" method you linked to only applies if you're using Gradle, which I'm not and the original question title includes "non-gradle". ;)

Comment: According to @Kurt, if the "Create module from existing sources" isn't available in Step 3 of the Android Studio instructions, you can just copy the `google-play_services.jar` into your `libs` directory and then right click on the `.jar` and choose "Add As Library". Thanks Kurt!

Comment: Is this still possible in 2018? Seems like it's missing the `libproject` library in the SDK/extras/google folder.