# Eclipse IDE wont import my android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I have one android project which I have Created on another computer machine on eclipse IDE. But now when I am going to Import same project in my another laptop then its showing error as "No projects are found to import" please somebody Help me as early as possible..

THANK YOU...!!!

Comment: Create new blank project first and then import all files and class.

Comment: Isn't it a same question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/15414170/4404791

Comment: Great ....Does that my "Blank project" advice solved your issue? Or you got answer from that duplicate I mentioned?

Comment: I Followed your advice. @HelpingHands